# SQL Server Express unable to set login password

Tags: sql-server

I've installed SQL Server Express 2019 on a Windows machine for Sitecore development. I had a hard drive crash and needed to rebuild; prior to the crash everything was working fine.

Mixed authentication is enabled, as is the SA account.

The Sitecore installer can connect to my local instance, and sets up the database structure, including a set of database logins. Everything looks OK in SSMS and initially works - I get the Welcome to Sitecore page.

However, connecting to SSMS and then trying to log in with the passwords Sitecore generated fails. When I try to set them in SQL Server, they don't take (I always get a bad password error).

I've tried as both my Windows account (which installed SQL Server) and as the `sa` account I configured at install. Also tried running as administrator.

The GUI and scripts seem to work fine, but the passwords never seem to get set. Prior to the crash I could connect to SSMS using the generated logins, and verify connectivity.

I'm at a loss where to go from here, other than imaging the machine and reinstalling a fresh copy of Windows.

Comment: SQL Server has [password complexity requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy). Is it possible you are using passwords that are "too simple" and had previously disabled `CHECK_POLICY` so as to make use of them?

Comment: I tried that too - no luck. I was finally able to get it working by deleting the users Sitecore's installer created (database users) and creating them as users with logins. My DB is SQL Express, so I don't know if this is a quirk with the installer and SQL Express or some kind of bug.

Comment: I think that may have been it - I didn't remove the strong password requirement after installing SQL Server, and Sitecore's default passwords don't meet my organization's rules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you had to reinstall SQL Server and then perform a database restore from a backup.

If this was the case, the users in the database, after the restore, were "orphaned", as they had no corresponding login in the master database. Even if Sitecore did create logins, they would have different SIDs to the users in the Sitecore database. The only way work with those users, would have been to restore a backup of the master database, in which case both server logins and database users would have had the same SIDs.

Failing that, your only option was to delete the users and re-create the logins and users correctly, which you did.

For future reference check out Microsoft's documentation on [troubleshooting orphaned users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server.

So, no, this was not "a quirk with the installer and SQL Express or some kind of bug." ;-)

HTH Sean

Comment: I think you're partially right; they definitely weren't orphaned. I suspect it had to do with password complexity when the users were created by the Sitecore installer. I wish they'd provide an option for strong auto-generated passwords at install time.